# AIR HTML Apllication. Yow I can listen for new windows openning

Tags: html, events, air

The main HTML window of my application some like this:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <a id="a1" href="http://www.example.com/" target="_blank" >Link</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

How I can listen for events occurring when opening new windows by clicking on the link?

Comment: You'll need to explain in more detail, what you want to achieve.